# Как получить доступ к переменной объекта?

Tags: php

Есть вот такой объект:

```
JPagination Object
(
[limitstart] => 15
[limit] => 5
[total] => 16
[_viewall] => 
[_errors] => Array
    (
    )

[pages.total] => 4
[pages.current] => 4
[pages.start] => 1
[pages.stop] => 4
)
```

Мне нужно изменить pages.total,
$this->pagination->??? = 5

Пока только ошибки получаю, как ни пробовал.

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если php version > 5.3, то:

```
$obj_prop = 'pages.total';

$obj = new JPagination();
$obj->$obj_prop = 5;
```

**Добавление.**

Совсем забыл, если php до 5.3, то можно юзать функции `call_user_func` и `call_user_func_array`.

Comment: Спасибо, но я уже нашел решение, вот так: `$pagination->{'pages.total'} = 5;`